# What happens to a (running) for loop in Django view if the view is reloaded?

Tags: python, django, loops

Let's say following is a Django view:

```
def loop_view(request):
     for i in range(9999):
          print(i)
```

A user opens the view, the loop starts and while it was still running, the user reloads the view and the loop starts again but on the console, it is still printing from the previous loop, i.e. two loops are running simultaneously.

What is the best way to avoid this ?

Using Django 1.9.7 with python 3.5, deployed with apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi

Thanks

Comment: The behavior on a canceled request will depend on how you have deployed Django and how that solution is configured. There are other things to take into account as well. So please describe your environment as detailed as possible.

Comment: Why not just try it?